# How do I make FFPLAY automatically skip ahead while playing a stream without distorting audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming, buffer, video-playback

I've been a long time lurker, but now I've gone and made an account.

Like I said in the title, I want to play an SRT stream with FFPLAY, but whenever a drop in the connection happens, I need it to just force straight to the latest data.

Here's the command I'm using right now:

`ffplay -probesize 512 -analyzeduration 200000 -fflags nobuffer+fastseek+flush_packets -sync ext -flags low_delay -framedrop -i srt://my.domain.name:44234?latency=250000 -x 1280 -y 720`

Basically, I need a system that is more or less foolproof for non techy people. I need sub-second latency for everyone in the production crew to monitor what's going on in real-time, over the internet. SRT works perfectly for that. But finding a player that can play back reliably has been really difficult.

I've also tried using MPV but it has a similar problem. I can't get it to seek ahead when a drop happens at all.

VLC 4.0 works ok, but it's still in nightly builds and still has weird issues.

Any help, or other program suggestions that could work would be greatly appreciated!

Before this I was using nimble server with an SRT input muxed into an SLDP video output that plays in a web browser, but the latency is higher than I would like, and stability isn't great.

Comment: Have you tried [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)?